# SharePoint 2010 - Documents Opening Slowly in Office 2010 & 2013

Tags: office

Recently Documents have been opening extremely slowly on computers that are on the immediate network from the SharePoint servers. It is happening in Office 2010 and Office 2013. At times it can be about 30 seconds after confirming to open the document before it launches the appropriate application. Interesting to note, a computer that is not on the domain but is accessing via VPN is able to open the same documents instantaneously. Documents are coming from a document library and are only Office files. The problem does not seem to occur on .PDF or Image files that are held in the same library.

Thus far:

- Attempted Fiddler to look into authentication issues. - None found
- Ran Developer tools on IE11 to try to narrow down a particular script
  that hangs - None Found
- Disabled McAfee on both server and workstation to rule out on access
  scanning causing issues - No Resolution
- Updated Content Databases and installed latest hotfixes on SharePoint
  Farm
- Verified latest version of Office 2010 and Office 2013 are installed
- Lowered the settings for Office Upload Tool to removing caching and
  duplicate files being held.
- Unchecked "Auto Detect Proxy" in IE

Any assistance or ideas would be great, I've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some issues with certain antiviruses. But If you're using Windows Vista/7 or above, you might be having problems because there are dots in your SharePoint URL (go figure :))

This fix worked for me
http://www.sharepointboris.net/2010/03/windows-7vista-trouble-with-sharepoints-explorer-view-and-office-documents-freezing-or-prompting-for-user-credentials/